# Google Search Console no hreflang return tag

Tags: seo, google-search

I am trying to add herflang in my website, but I got some errors on google search console.

```
URLs for your site and alternate URLs in 'zh-Hans-CN' that do not have return tags 
URLs for your site and alternate URLs in 'zh-Hant-TW' that do not have return tags 
URLs for your site and alternate URLs in 'en-US' that do not have return tags
```

I don't have specific `urls` for different language, but I do use `I18n` to display different languages.

According to this [document](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6059209?authuser=1), I add following code into `<head>` 
element.

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="zh-Hant-TW">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="zh-Hans-CN">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="en-US">
```

I only add above code in my landing page, should I add it in all pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can do want you are hoping to do. It needs to be an actual translation with its own directory at minimum. It is all there in the link you shared.

So even if you were able to make a second translation, if generated it will not be effective. Pseudo Translations come with far too many errors and is also not considered a good version of the language.

**On top of that. From Google.**

> Q: Can I use automated translations?
>
> A: Yes, but they must be blocked from indexing with the “noindex”
>   robots meta tag. We consider automated translations to be
>   auto-generated content, so allowing them to be indexed would be a
>   violation of our Webmaster Guidelines.

I am sorry.

Comment: I am confused about `actual translation`, is that mean I can't only use `i18n`? I need to create a specific language page for each of `en`, `tw` and `cn`, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. You can use it on your website but not as an official translation and Google will not recognize it as one. The only way it can work with i18n is if all formatting is stripped so it minimizes errors in auto translated content. Then you still have to have a separate directory for the language and point to that Url..

Comment: Thanks, so probably only different landing page is fine.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and making sure there is a clear link back to the original language page. You are welcome.

Comment: I was wondering that if `query string` works or not? Like `www.example.com/?lang=en`.

Comment: Thats used as a search method for pages in this case ENglish language. It does not take auto translations into consideration or else a simple Google translator on your site would work as secondary language pages, which it does not for indexing.

Answer (score 2):

You should have different URL for different language, that is how Google know your all alternative pages with different languages.

You're doing same mistake like [this guy did](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100956/implementing-the-hreflang-tag-in-the-head/100961).